# Defining words as 2 letters or more in python 2.6

Tags: python, lambda, text-processing

I have a python script that I am writing for a class assignment which calculates the top 10 most frequent words in a text document and displays the words and their frequency. I was able to get this part of the script working just fine, but the assignment says a word is defined as **2 letters or more**. I cannot seem to define a word as 2 letters or more for some reason, when I run the script, nothing happens.

```
# Most Frequent Words:
from string import punctuation
from collections import defaultdict

def sort_words(x, y):
    return cmp(x[1], y[1]) or cmp(y[0], x[0])

number = 10
words = {}

words_gen = (word.strip(punctuation).lower() for line in open("charactermask.txt")
                                             for word in line.split())
words = defaultdict(int)
for word in words_gen:
    words[word] +=1

letters = len(word)

while letters >= 2:
    top_words = sorted(words.iteritems(),
                        key=lambda(word, count): (-count, word))[:number] 

for word, frequency in top_words:
    print "%s: %d" % (word, frequency)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refactor your code <strike>and use a `collections.Counter` object</strike>:

```
import collections
import string

with open("charactermask.txt") as f:
  words = [x.strip(string.punctuation).lower() for x in f.read().split()]

counter = collections.defaultdict(int):
for word in words:
  if len(word) >= 2:
    counter[word] += 1
```

Comment: collections.Counter object is not offered in python 2.6.

Comment: oh right, you can use a `defaultdict(int)` as you have been then

Comment: I can see why this would work, but I implemented it and now I am back to not getting a return at all...

Answer (score 2):

One problem with your script is the loop

```
while letters >= 2:
    top_words = sorted(words.iteritems(),
                        key=lambda(word, count): (-count, word))[:number]
```

You are not looping through the words here; this loop will just loop forever. You need to change the script so that this part of the script actually iterates over all of the words. (Also, you will probably want to change `while` to `if` because you only need that code to execute once per word.)

Comment: I changed the while to if, and now I am at least getting a return of the words, but it still includes the letter 'a' as a word. How can I make this iterate over all the words?